# update() a model inside a function with local covariate

Tags: r, glm, lm

I need to update a regression model from inside a function. Ideally, the function should work with any kind of models (`lm`, `glm`, `multinom`, `clm`). More precisely, I need to add one or several covariates that are defined inside the function. Here is an exemple.

```
MyUpdate <- function(model){
     randData <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(length(model$residuals)))
     model2 <- update(model, ".~.+randData$var1")
     return(model2)
}
```

Here is an example use

```
data(iris)
model1 <- lm(Sepal.Length~Species, data=iris)
model2 <- MyUpdate(model1)
```

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'randData' not found

Here is another example with glm

```
model1 <- glm(Sepal.Length>5~Species, data=iris, family=binomial)
model2 <- MyUpdate(model1)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `var1` is looked up in the data frame and the model's environment but not within the environment in `MyUpdate`.

**1)** To avoid this problem update the model with not only the revised formula but also a revised data frame containing `var1` :

```
MyUpdate <- function(model) {
     mf <- model.frame(model)
     n <- nrow(mf)
     var1 <- rnorm(n)
     update(model, formula = . ~ . + var1, data = data.frame(mf, var1))
}
```

The above is probably the best solution of the ones presented in this answer as it avoids mucking around with internal structures. It seems to work for `lm`, `glm`, `multinom` and `clm`.  The other solutions below do muck around with internal structures and therefore are less general across model fitting routines.  The others all work with `lm` but may not work for others.

**test** Here is a test which runs without errors on each of the model fitting functions mentioned in the question if `MyUpdate` is as above and also the solutions in (2) all run the tests without error.  The solution (3) works at least with `lm`.

```
model.lm <- lm(Sepal.Length~Species, data=iris)
MyUpdate(model.lm)

model.glm <- glm(Sepal.Length~Species, data=iris)
MyUpdate(model.glm)

library(nnet)
example(multinom)
MyUpdate(bwt.mu)

library(ordinal)
model.clm <- clm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine)
MyUpdate(model.clm)
```

The remaining solutions perform more direct access of internals making them less robust to changing the model function.

**2) Messing with Environments**

In addition here are three solutions that involve messing with environments. The first is the cleanest followed by the second and then the third.  The third is the least acceptable since it actually writes `var1` into the model's environment (dangerously overwriting any `var1` there) but it is the shortest.   They work with `lm`, `glm` `multinom` and `clm`.

Note that we do not really need to put `var1` into a data frame nor is it necessary to put the updating formula in quotes and we have changed both in all examples below.  Also the `return` statement can be removed and we have done that too.

**2a)** The following modifies the environment of the original model to point to a new proxy proto object containing `var1` whose parent is the original model environment.  Here `proto(p, var1 = rnorm(n))` is the proxy proto object (a proto object is an environment with differing semantics) and `p` is the parent of the proxy.

```
library(proto)

MyUpdate <- function(model){

     mf <- model.frame(model)
     n <- nrow(mf)
     var1 <- rnorm(n)
     p <- environment(formula(model))

     if (is.null(model$formula)) {
           attr(model$terms, ".Environment") <- proto(p, var1 = var1)
     } else environment(model$formula) <- proto(p, var1 = var1)

     update(model, . ~ . + var1) 
}

#note: the period is shorthand for 
keep everything on either the left or right hand side 
of the formula (i.e., the ~) and 
the + or - sign are used to add or remove model terms
```

For more information read the Proxies section in this document: http://r-proto.googlecode.com/files/prototype_approaches.pdf

**2b)** This could alternately be done without proto but at the expense of expanding the ## line to three lines containing some additional ugly environment manipulations.  Here `e` is the proxy environment.

```
MyUpdate <- function(model){
     mf <- model.frame(model)
     n <- nrow(mf)
     var1 <- rnorm(n)
     p <- environment(formula(model))

     e <- new.env(parent = p)
     e$var1 <- var1

     if (is.null(model$formula)) attr(model$terms, ".Environment") <- e
     else environment(model$formula) <- e

     update(model, . ~ . + var1)
}
```

**2c)** Shortest but the most hackish is to stick `var1` into the original `model` environment:

```
MyUpdate <- function(model){
     mf <- model.frame(model)
     n <- nrow(mf)
     var1 <- rnorm(n)       

     if (is.null(model$formula)) attr(model$terms, ".Environment")$var1 <- var1
     else environment(model$formula)$var1 <- var1

     update(model, . ~ . + var1)
}
```

**3) eval/substitute**  This solution does use `eval` which is sometimes frowned upon.  It works on `lm` and `glm` and on `clm` it works except that the output does not display `var1` but rather the expression that computes it.

```
MyUpdate <- function(model) {
     m <- eval.parent(substitute(update(model, . ~ . + rnorm(nrow(model.frame(model))))))
     m$call$formula <- update(formula(model), . ~ . + var1)
     names(m$coefficients)[length(m$coefficient)] <- "var1"
     m
}
```

**REVISED** Added additional solutions, simplified (1), got solutions in (2) to run all examples in test section.

Comment: Many thanks for detailed and comprehensive answer! I am pretty sure that using environment is the way to go, however, it do not work with glm (I don't understand why).

Comment: Have revised so that the first solution works on `lm`, `glm`, `multinom` and `clm`.  It is the most general as it does the least accessing of internals. The other solutions above work at least on `lm`.

Comment: This is really a good answer. Thank you for explaining why the first solution is the best one.

Comment: Have simplified `MyUpdate` in (1).

Comment: Have improved the 3 solutions in (2) so that now they run the 4 examples in the test section without error.  (3) still runs only a subset of them.

Answer (score 3):

**Some theory**. A formula object often has an associated environment:

```
frm1 <- y~x # a formula created in the global environment ("in the console")
attr(frm1, ".Environment") # see also unclass(frm1)
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Here, the functions acting on `frm1` will know that they shall seek for `y` and `x` in the global environment (unless stated otherwise, see e.g. `data` arg of `lm()`). On the other hand:

```
f <- function() { y~x }; frm2 <- f() # a formula created in a function
attr(frm2, ".Environment")
## <environment: 0x2f87e48>
```

Such a formula points to `y` and `x` being the "local variables" in `f()`.

If you pass a formula created in the global environment to a function, you will is most cases not be able to refer to the objects created within that function.

**The solution**. The underlying formula and environment is somewhat "hidden" withing the object returned by `lm()`. But they can be accessed. The code below should solve your issue.

```
MyUpdate <- function(model){
     assign("randData", data.frame(var1=rnorm(length(model$residuals))),
        envir=attr(model1$terms, ".Environment"))
     model2 <- update(model, ".~.+randData$var1")
     return(model2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! However, I don't want to modify the original environment.